# Problema na alocação de memoria, com valores grandes

Tags: c, malloc

Bom estou com problema em uma questão

Enunciado

Dado um vetor de inteiros, sua tarefa é encontrar a k-ésima ocorrência (da esquerda para a direita) de um inteiro v no vetor. Para tornar o problema mais difícil (e mais interessante!), você deve responder a m consultas deste tipo.

Entrada de dos casos de teste

```
8 4
1 3 2 2 4 3 2 1
1 3
2 4
3 2
4 2
```

Nesse caso 1,3 eu estou procurando o numero 3, na sua primeira ocorrencia no meu vetor, por isso eu utilizo o numero como indice, o resultado e 2, como meu código faz

Lógica que eu usei na questão

para resolver esse problema eu usei a seguinte lógica, criei a struct elemento que vai receber o valor e o indice, depois criei a struct Map nela vai ter uma matriz da struct elemento, e um array de tamanho que vai ter os tamanho dos indice da minha struct, por isso quando eu chamo a função cria() eu uso o calloc que zera o meu vetor, na função de insere, eu verifico se o indice que eu estou inserindo e 0, por que se for significa que não exite elementos nesse indice, e preencho os dados normalmente, quando é no else, eu utilizo o realloc, para adicionar o elemento, na minha matriz.

Meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct elemento
{
    int valor, chave;
} Elemento;

typedef struct map
{
    Elemento **dados;
    int *tamanho;
} Map;

Map *cria(int tam);
int insere(Map *mp, int valor, int i);
Map *libera(Map *mp, int tam);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int tam, teste;
    int numero, indice;
    int i;
    while(scanf("%d %d", &tam, &teste) != EOF)
    {
        Map *matriz = cria(tam);
        for(i = 0; i < tam; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &numero);
            insere(matriz, numero, i + 1);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d %d", &indice, &numero);
            if(indice <= matriz->tamanho[numero])
            {
                printf("%d\n", matriz->dados[numero][indice - 1].chave);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("0");
            }
        }
        matriz = libera(matriz, tam);
    }

    return 0;
}

Map *cria(int tam)
{
    Map *mp = malloc(sizeof(Map));
    if(!mp) return NULL;
    mp->tamanho = calloc(tam, sizeof(int));
    mp->dados = malloc(sizeof(Elemento*) * tam);
    return mp;
}

int insere(Map *mp, int valor, int i)
{
    if(mp->tamanho[valor] == 0)
    {
        mp->dados[valor] = malloc(sizeof(Elemento));
        mp->dados[valor][0].valor = valor;
        mp->dados[valor][0].chave = i;
        mp->tamanho[valor]++;
    }
    else
    {
        int size = mp->tamanho[valor];
        mp->dados[valor] = realloc(mp->dados[valor], (size + 1) * sizeof(Elemento));
        mp->dados[valor][size].valor = valor;
        mp->dados[valor][size].chave = i;
        mp->tamanho[valor]++;
    }
    return 1;
}

Map *libera(Map *mp, int tam)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        free(mp->dados[i]);
    }
    free(mp);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Sinceramente não entendi sua interpretação do problema e muito menos a lógica de sua solução.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta, na sessão Lógica que eu usei na questão, eu falo a logica que eu usei, deu pra entender melhor ?

Comment: Não, na função `insere` você utiliza o valor fornecido como índice. Qual o sentido disso?

Comment: coloquei os casos de teste na descrição agora, obrigado por está tentando me ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi do problema, e me orientando pelo princípio [KISS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_KISS), eu faria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int tam, casos, ocor, num, *vet, i, j, k, l;
    scanf("%d %d", &tam, &casos);
    vet = malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    if (vet == NULL)
        exit(1);
    for (i=0; i<tam; i++)
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    for (j=0; j<casos; j++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &ocor, &num);
        k = 0;
        for (l=0; l<tam && k<ocor; l++)
            if (vet[l] == num)
                k++;
        if (k == ocor)
            printf("A %dª ocorrência de %d encontra-se na posição %d\n", ocor, num, l);
        else
            printf("Não existem %d ocorrências de %d no vetor\n", ocor, num);
    }
    free(vet);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O resultado da certo com os casos de testes, mas o tempo de execução está alto, deixa quieto então questão dificil kkkk